# What's the best way to give a dependency property a default value from a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf

I'd like to create a WPF user control (or custom control). The user of this control should be able to re-template a certain part of this control. For that I created a dependency property called "SubTemplate".

```
Public Shared ReadOnly SubTemplateProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SubTemplate", GetType(DataTemplate), GetType(MyControl), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing))
```

Of course there should be a default template that's used, when the user doesn't give it's own template. But how do I give this default value to the dependency property?

I'd like to define this default template in XAML (probably in a resource dictionary, maybe in Themes\Generic.xaml?)

Is there a way to exchange the `Nothing` default value with a template from a resource dictionary?

Or do I have to set the default value in the constructor of my control (still don't know how to access a named template from a resource dictionary in code behind, `FindResource` doesn't seem to work or I'm using it wrong).

Or do I have to set the `TargetNullValue` of the binding I use to add the template to the re-templated part of the control?

Right now I just set the "SubTemplate" property in the default style of my control, but if the user restyles the whole control and forgets to give a "SubTemplate", then it would be `Nothing`.

Comment: Do it in the default style for the control. If the user restyles the whole control and makes a mess of it, that's out of your control.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a template or datatemplate in a resource dictionary? They want a different bit of UI, they define a new template in their own resourcedictionary with the same target key which overrides your default template.

Comment: Errm…. you mean the standard mechanism used in wpf to link a control to it's template by it's key of Type?

Comment: @Andy I'm familiar with implicit datatemplates and default styles. There's no such thing as an implicit ControlTemplate, AFAIK. What would be the DataType for "SubTemplate" here? Anyway, clearly I misunderstood you. Zapped it.

Comment: Fair point. I was assuming he has something there.

Comment: The data type of "SubTemplate" would be `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate`, I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to exchange the `Nothing` default value with a template from a resource dictionary?

If you add the default `DataTemplate` to your `App.xaml` file, this should work:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly SubTemplateProperty As DependencyProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("SubTemplate", GetType(DataTemplate), GetType(MyControl), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Application.Current.Resources("KeyOfTemplate")))
```

If you want more control over things you could write some code that looks up the template, for example in the `OnApplyTemplate` method of the control. You may want to get it from somewhere else, check that it actually exists, etc.

Comment: If my control is in a control library, then there's no `Application.xaml` (at least not in my library).

Comment: @Nostromo: No, of course not. Then you need to write some code that finds the template wherever it's located.

Comment: So there's no built-in way to get a named resource from let's say "Themes\Generic.xaml"?

Comment: @Nostromo: Just create a new `ResourceDictionary` object and set its `Uri` property: `new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml") }`. You can then access any of its resources as usual. But there is no static property that gives you access to the resources in generic.xaml.

Comment: I'll try to use that in the constructor of my control, thank you.

Comment: I tried several `uriString`s, but I always get "can't find resource file". I tried it inside the "Themes" folder and in the root folder of my project, I tried all `uriString` formats I found in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframework-4.8), nothing seems to work. I tried several build actions for my resource file (like `Resource`, `Embedded Resource` or `Content`). What else could I try?

Comment: The `Build Action` of the `ResourceDictionary` should be `Page` and the pack URI should be `pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/themes/generic.xaml` where `AssemblyName` is the name of the assembly in which `generic.xaml` is defined.